# COUNT (DISTINCT) With Condition

Tags: mysql, select, db2

I have 3 tables to retrieve the values from in a single Select statement which are

`DISCUSSION`,`USER_INFO` & `DISCUSSION_COMMENT.`

In `DISCUSSION_COMMENT`, I got a `USER_ID` column where i need to count distinct entries.

here I used

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) FROM DISCUSSION_COMMENT`

and its working fine.

But i need make a single select statement to get all the row values from

`DISCUSSION`,`USER_INFO` and using the value `DIS_ID` in `DISCUSSION` to to find the total count

from `DISCUSSION_COMMENT` table like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) 
FROM DISCUSSION_COMMENT
WHERE DISCUSSION_COMMENT.DIS_ID=DISCUSSION.DIS_ID
```

where DIS_ID is my foreign key in DISCUSSION_COMMENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear. It *seems* like you need to join:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SCHEMA.USER_ID) 
FROM DISCUSSION_COMMENT
JOIN DISCUSSION ON DISCUSSION_COMMENT.DIS_ID=DISCUSSION.DIS_ID
```

In English, this will count the number of different users who have commented on a discussion.

If you have referential integrity on the foreign key column, you can just check if DIS_ID is not null:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SCHEMA.USER_ID) 
FROM DISCUSSION_COMMENT
WHERE DIS_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Bohemian, I also suggest you do not use COUNT() in MySQL query, if the number of rows is large this cause stress to the server, you can get the total result with native count() function in PHP or equivalent in the programming language that your coding.

Comment: This is a bad solution. Returning all rows will be at least as slow as counting them on the database server. If you need to optimize around MySQL limitations, you could create a `comment_count` column in the discussion table and update it whenever you create or delete a comment.

Comment: It is also a good option to use @Leons, use anything minus the COUNT in sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a MySQL question or a DB2 question? Both are tagged.

For DB2, I would suggest an aggregate query:

```
SELECT COUNT(dc.user_id), dc.dis_id
FROM discussion_comment dc, discussion d
GROUP BY dc.dis_id
HAVING dc.dis_id = d.dis_id
```